# Iterating over object keys while allowing for empty string

Tags: javascript, object

I'm trying to write a function that trims all the values on each value on an object. It is working correctly however when someone adds a few spaces, it is getting saved as "", however I need it to save as "null"
In the example above, I need the email field to come back as null when someone adds a input of "     ", however it is coming back as ""

```
contact: {
  firstName: "John"
  lastName: "Smith"
  homePhone: null
  email: ""
}

Object.keys(contact).forEach(
  k =>
(contact[k] =
  typeof contact[k] == 'string'
    ? contact[k].trim()
    : contact[k])
)
```

Comment: `? (contact[k].trim() ? contact[k].trim() : null)` or `? (contact[k].trim() || null)`

Answer (score 3):

First check it's a string, and if so trim it, and return the trimmed string if it still has length > 0.

```
let tidy = x => {
    if (typeof x === "string") {
        x = x.trim();
        if (x.length > 0) {
            return x;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    } 
    return x;
};
Object.keys(contact).forEach(k => contact[k] = tidy(contact[k]));
```